# Apache status giving a negative number of connections?

Tags: linux, apache

When I issue the command "apachectl status" i sometimes get a nice normal number of connections /sec.
At other times, i get a negative number.. Sometimes it shows something random like 2e3^E

What on earth is going on?

Im trying to troubleshoot a problem where some pages dont load and i get a waiting for socket error in chrome. Yet CPU etc is all fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Graham

```
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12288; Current requests/sec: 78.2; Current traffic: 314KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12266; Current requests/sec: -2.44; Current traffic: 5.2KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12266; Current requests/sec: -2.44; Current traffic: 5.2KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12266; Current requests/sec: -2.44; Current traffic: 5.2KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12266; Current requests/sec: -2.44; Current traffic: 5.2KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12266; Current requests/sec: -2.44; Current traffic: 5.2KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12266; Current requests/sec: -2.44; Current traffic: 5.2KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12828; Current requests/sec: 56.2; Current traffic: 149KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12828; Current requests/sec: 56.2; Current traffic: 149KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12828; Current requests/sec: 56.2; Current traffic: 149KB/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12825; Current requests/sec: -0.375; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
[root@console ~]# apachectl status | grep Status
   Status: "Total requests: 12825; Current requests/sec: -0.375; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
```

Comment: Well, the count for total number of requests goes down as well, so I can see how the difference would turn out negative. That doesn't explain why the number goes down, though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorta fixed it..

I have a feeling it was hitting the max connected users on apache.

So, I modified prefork mpm to allow a lot more users and installed mod-status to keep an eye on it.

Since then it all seems fairly happy with plenty of idle workers and lots of free connection slots.

Luckily, the server has plenty of free ram and is on raided SSD's anyway ( should thrashing ever happen )